# How to test deinit of viewController

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, memory-leaks, xctest

I want to test if I remove all the key value observers in the `deinit` of my view controller.

In the test class I have defined following method to start view controller lifecycle

```
  func startLifecycle() {
   _ = viewController.view
  }
```

In my test method I'm trying to invoke `deinit` by simply assigning nil to my view controller instance

```
testViewController = nil
XCTAssert for stuff...
```

But `deinit` is not called when I execute my test. I see no obvious retain cycles in my VC's code, what's more when I run the code in my app, not the test environment, `deinit` is called so it doesn't seem like something is keeping view controller in memory.

What is the correct way to release a view controller when testing?

Comment: I suppose you can have a `weak` reference to a viewController, then set the viewController to `nil` and then check to see if your reference to the viewController is `nil` or not...No need to use use a `deinit` in that case.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

When you examine the memory graph, you will see that an object of type `UIStoryboardScene` maintains a reference to your `UIViewController` via an `@autorelease` property '`sceneViewController`'.

If you're unfamiliar with @autorelease, this is a helpful article: https://swiftrocks.com/autoreleasepool-in-swift. It explains that objects created with autorelease are released at the end of the current thread's run loop, but not before.

In Swift, we can use `autoreleasepool` to release `UIStoryboardScene`'s reference to the UIViewController.

It might look something like this:

```
var testViewController: UIViewController?
autoreleasepool {
    testViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
}
```

Then, when you execute `testViewController = nil`, the UIViewController will actually deinit.

Comment: updated blog link: https://swiftrocks.com/autoreleasepool-in-swift

Answer (score 2):

Try smth like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var deinitCalled: (() -> Void)?
    deinit { deinitCalled?() }
}

class ViewControllerTest: XCTestCase {
    func test_deinit() { 
        var instance: ViewController? = ViewController()
        let exp = expectation(description: "Viewcontroller has deinited")
        instance?.deinitCalled = {
            exp.fulfill()
        }

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            instance = nil
        }

        waitForExpectations(timeout: 2)
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you can have a `weak` reference to a viewController, then set the viewController to `nil` and then check to see if your reference to the viewController is `nil` or not...No need to use use a `deinit` and expectation in that case

Comment: Even though the main answer is right but the @Honey 's comment is by far easier to implement. So I pick up this one specially because it does not need to modify the type under the test.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else needs this i managed to do it this way.

```
    // Given
    var optionalSubject: UIViewController? = UIViewController()

    // When
    optionalSubject = nil // Call deinit

    // Then
    // TEST DEINIT
```